# How to get a prompt after each while loop iteration?

Tags: linux, bash, prompt

I want a prompt after each loop iteration.

FOR EXAMPLE : When one iteration is performed, I need `Press Enter to continue` and then again after second iteration, again after third and so on.

I am using `read -p " Press enter to continue "` (but this is getting skipped ).

```
while read line

do

echo "$line" logs""

echo " "

echo "`tail -100 Domain1."$line"`"

read -p "Press enter to continue"

done<input.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `read -p` inside the loop is getting "skipped" (not really) because it's reading from `input.txt`.  All commands inside the loop will inherit their standard input stream from the loop by default, and this is connected to `input.txt`

Instead, you will have to make the `read line` read from a new input file descriptor, and have the file's contents delivered over that:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
    printf '%s logs\n\n' "$line"
    tail -n 100 "Domain1.$line"
    read -p 'Press Enter to continue'
done 3<input.txt
```

Here, we use file descriptor 3 (the next free and available file descriptor after the standard ones) and connect it to the input file. We then ask `read line` explicitly to read from *that* file descriptor, rather than from its standard input (file descriptor 0).  This leaves standard input free, and the `read -p` will read from that as usual.

Alternatively, you could swap the input file descriptors around from the above loop:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s logs\n\n' "$line"
    tail -n 100 "Domain1.$line"
    read -p 'Press Enter to continue' <&3
done 3<&0 <input.txt
```

Now the `read line` reads from the file through the ordinary standard input inherited from the loop while `read -p` reads from file descriptor 3.  File descriptor 3 is opened as a copy of standard input before standard input is redirected from the file.

In the `bash` shell,

```
read <&3
```

could also be written

```
read -u 3
```

So the "cleanest" solution (in the sense of containing the least amount of file descriptor juggling syntax) may be something like

```bash
while IFS= read -u 3 -r line; do
    printf '%s logs\n\n' "$line"
    tail -n 100 "Domain1.$line"
    read -p 'Press Enter to continue'
done 3<input.txt
```

Comment: thankyou so much, I have one more question

Comment: I am actually now capturing running logs, so (tail -100f "Domain1.$line",) is replaced by tail -100f "Domain1.$line" in my code. I want each iteration of while loop to run for 20 seconds and then come out of it and ask me "press enter to continue".

Comment: @ShivamMalhotra `tail -f` will not exit by itself (you would have to interrupt it). You may want to ask a new question about that specific detail (as it's unrelated to your original question).

Comment: actually I am not able to ask a new question right now. reached the limit can you please help it here only. what can I do. if tail -f will not exit by itself. any alternative?????